# VueJS $emit and $on not working in one component to another component page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, eventemitter, vue-events

I am trying to long time Vue `$emit` and `$on` functionality but still I am not getting any solution. I created simple message passing page its two pages only. One is `Component Sender` and `Component Receiver` and added `eventbus` for `$emit` and `$on` functionality.

I declared `$emit` and `$on` functionality but I don't know where I made a mistake.

please help some one.

**Component Sender:**

```js
    <script>
    import { EventBus } from '../main';
    export default {
        name: 'Send',
        data () {
            return {
                text: '',
                receiveText: ''
            }
        },

        methods: {
            sender() {
                 EventBus.$emit('message', this.text);
                 this.$router.push('/receive');
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**Component Receiver:**

```js
    <script>
    import { EventBus } from '../main';
    export default {
        name: 'Receive',
        props: ["message"],
        data () {
            return {
                list: null
            }
        },
        created() {
            EventBus.$on('message', this.Receive);

        },
        methods: {
            Receive(text){
                console.log('text', text);
                this.list = text;
            },
            save() {
                alert('list', this.list);//need to list value but $emit is not working here

            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

**Router View:**

```js
    const router = new Router({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            {
                path: "/",
                name: "Send",
                component: Send
            },
            {
                path: "/receive",
                name: "Receive",
                component: Receive,
                props: true
            }
        ]
    })
```

**Main.JS**

```js
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import App from './App.vue'
    import router from './router';

    export const EventBus = new Vue();

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    })
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Did you open two tabs and then load the pages on the tab on your browser?

Comment: What is triggering your `sender() ` method?

Comment: Hi Onwuka, Just i passed click event save emit value after redirect to receiver page.But I did't get any $on trigger event in Receiver page.

Comment: Hi Short, I need to get $on trigger event for Receiver page

Answer (score 1):

The EventBus is designed to allow communication between two components that exist on the page at *the same time*. If you need data that persists between router-views, then you should look at using a Vuex store.

As it is, the Receiver component doesn't exist at the time of the message being sent, and therefore it has no listener attached to the event.

Answer (score 1):

Well your mistake is here:

```
created() {
       EventBus.$on('message', this.Receive);
    },
```

the second argument is an handler it should look like this:

```
created() {
        EventBus.$on('message', function(data){
           this.Receive(data);
           console.log(data)
        });

    },
```

you should see now 2 `console.log()` messages